# AndEngine portrait distortion with RotationModifier

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine to try and create a simple sprite of a ball rotating 360 degrees constantly. The rotation is working fine. However, the picture of the ball looks distorted ONLY in portrait mode.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

You'll notice how in Portrait mode the ball seems to be stretching upwards. I'm not sure what could be causing this. I would just like the ball to remain perfectly circular.

In case anybody asks.. the ball image is perfectly circular and is 200px x 200px.

Here is my code:

```
Ball = new Sprite(100, 100, 200, 200, this.BallRegion);

LoopEntityModifier EntityModifier = 
             new LoopEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(10, 0, 360));          
Ball.registerEntityModifier(EntityModifier);

scene.attachChild(Ball);
```

My resolution policy:

```
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine(new EngineOptions(true,
            null, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
            this.mCamera));
```

Comment: this is probably more related to the ResolutionPolicy you set when you initialized things

Comment: I have now included my resolution policy

Comment: It seems my CAMERA_WIDTH was larger than my CAMERA_HEIGHT. I switched the values and now portrait looks fine, but landscape is longer. Is it possible to set a new RatioResolutionPolicy AFTER it is first called?

Comment: I don't think you can change it on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. To handle the orientation change with a live wallpaper in AndEngine, you can use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        scene.setScale(1);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        scene.setScaleX(480.0f / 720.0f);
        scene.setScaleY(1.0f);
    }

            //Rebuilds the scene. onLoadScene() calls to this method.
    BuildScene();

}
```

You may have to alter the values depending on your resolution policy, but this works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

i took above solution and improve it:

when you create camera, make this:

```
Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

camera.setResizeOnSurfaceSizeChanged(true);
camera.setCenter( 0.5f * CAMERA_WIDTH
                , 0.5f * CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

then override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` :

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            getEngine().getCamera().setRotation(0);
        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            getEngine().getCamera().setRotation(90f);
        }
    }
```

also in this case, if you use accelerometer in your wallpaper, data from accelerometer should be corrected:

```
 @Override
 public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
     boolean isCameraRotated = getEngine().getCamera().isRotated();

        float correctAccelerationX = isCameraRotated ? pAccelerationData.getY() 
                                                     : pAccelerationData.getX();
        float correctAccelerationY = isCameraRotated ? pAccelerationData.getX() 
                                                     : pAccelerationData.getY() * -1;
  }
```